# Best way to make an image link in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want a picture of my product to link to the product show page. I've tried:

```
<%= link_to product.photos.first.image.url(:small), product%>
```

which produces

```
<a href="/products/64">/system/photos/images/000/000/023/small/4462867927_3741423c39_o.jpg?1395899030</a>
```

I've also tried

```
          <a href="<%= products_path(product) %>"> <%= image_tag product.photos.first.image.url(:small) %> </a>
```

which produces:

```
<a href="/products.64"> <img alt="4462867927 3741423c39 o" src="/system/photos/images/000/000/023/small/4462867927_3741423c39_o.jpg?1395899030"> </a>
```

And that's not right either. Whats the best way to do this in Rails?

Comment: The order of arguments in the first call of `link_to` is wrong. Its signature is `link_to(body, url, html_options = {})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%= link_to image_tag(product.photos.first.image.url(:small)), product %>`

Comment: thanks for the help that worked, should have noticed.